# Erro em aplicação asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou com o erro abaixo e não sei como resolver.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possar ser e como resolver?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Unable to copy file "C:\WORK\1-Arquivos
>   Pessoais\CarrinhoDeCompras\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\tools\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll"
>   to "bin\roslyn\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll". Access to the
>   path 'bin\roslyn\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll' is
>   denied.   CarrinhoDeCompras.UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando eu tive esse problema, eu resolvia finalizando o processo `VBCSCompiler.exe` e tudo voltava ao normal.

Mas após as ultimas atualizações do Visual Studio eu não tive mais esse problema.

Para finalizar o processo, você pode rodar o comando `taskkill /F /IM VBCSCompiler.exe` no cmd, ou procurar o processo no gerenciador de tarefas do Windows.